# centos samba folder share read as file

Tags: linux, mount, samba

i using centos 7 to mount a shared network folder (smth), then i share it (smth) using samba (ters), but the other computer (windows or linux) read the shared folder (ters) as file, so i can't open the directory, 
fyi: 
     /etc/fstab
          //10.11.12.13/smth /smth cifs auto,rw,uid=501,gid=501,username=xxxx,password=xxxx                           ,inode64  0 0

```
 /smb.conf
 [ters]
    writeable = yes
    path = /smth
    follow symlinks = yes
    wide links = yes
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 0777
```

[Read as file, it should be folder instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9P9p.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whats important here is the browseable setting:

```
[ters]
     writeable = yes
     browseable = yes
     path = /smth
     follow symlinks = yes
     wide links = yes
     create mode = 0777
     directory mode = 0777
```

Also make sure you restart your samba server after the changes(if you are on debian based, there are two services to restart [smbd and nmbd])